# Unable to ssh into running dropbear sshd. "Bad password attempt" ...But password is correct

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, alpine, dropbear

For some reason, a running dropbear sshd i've got going in a Docker container is telling me `Bad password attempt` , even though i've doublechecked multiple times that both username and password is 100% correct.

Dropbear is being started by `supervisord` with the following command:

> /usr/local/sbin/dropbear -F -E -p 2222

by a user and group 'mysticbbs'. No errors are coming up when dropbear runs..

However, when i try to ssh into the container from the host computer, with:

> ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null localhost -l mysticbbs -p 2222

*('-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' , to prevent storing lots of different keys generated during testing/building of the dockerfile)*

..ssh, like expected, gives me:

> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0WadKddpa*[..blabla.]*
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

I'm then asked for the password. But whether or not i type it in, or paste it in, 100% correctly..I still get `Permission denied, please try again.` and dropbear logs the attempt with `Bad password attempt for 'mysticbbs' from 172.17.0.1:35152` ..

- I've tried setting a different/more complex password
- Trying to ssh with `dbclient` from inside the container, with same user dropbear is running under, and running dropbear without using supervisord, makes no difference. (`Bad password attempt for 'mysticbbs' from 127.0.0.1:48110`) ..
- The /etc/dropbear folder (and the keys) is chowned to 'mysticbbs:mysticbbs' and chmod to 700
- The same problem occurs whether or not i use the `dropbear` from alpine's apk repo *(v2018.76-r2)*, or build it from dropbear.nl source *(both v2018.76 and v2017.75 tested)*..
- Deleting the keys and manually running dropbear with `-R` argument makes no difference.
- Found a notation at https://github.com/mkj/dropbear , but i can't see how that could apply since user attempted to ssh in *is the same* as the one running dropbear:

>

> *If the server is run as non-root, you most likely won't be able to
>   allocate a pty, and you cannot login as any user other than that
>   running the daemon (obviously). Shadow passwords will also be unusable
>   as non-root.*

- **Shadow passwords just might the culprit..**

Keys are generated during the docker build with the following:

```
   export RSA_KEYFILE=/etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
   export DSS_KEYFILE=/etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key
   export ECDSA_KEYFILE=/etc/dropbear/dropbear_ecdsa_host_key
   dropbearkey -t dss -f $DSS_KEYFILE
   dropbearkey -t rsa -f $RSA_KEYFILE
   dropbearkey -t ecdsa -f $ECDSA_KEYFILE
   chown -R mysticbbs:mysticbbs /etc/dropbear
   chmod -R 700 /etc/dropbear
```

password for mysticbbs user is set during docker build with:

```
   passwd mysticbbs -d '<password>' -u
```

**What am i missing?..**

Comment: You appear to have missed "Shadow passwords will also be unusable as non-root."

Comment: Indeed i have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed to by [@michael-hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) in comment, and the note at https://github.com/mkj/dropbear:

> *If the server is run as non-root, you most likely won't be able to
>   allocate a pty, and you cannot login as any user other than that
>   running the daemon (obviously). **Shadow passwords will also be unusable
>   as non-root**.*

My problems seems indeed to arise at **shadow passwords** when running dropbear as non-root user.

In [my specific case](https://github.com/DuckHP/mystic_bbs_docker), under *alpine:3.9/BusyBox*, <strike>it seems a more valid solution and workaround for me to add *root* to my '*mysticbbs*' group, and drop root privileges as needed, rather than make `/etc/shadow` accessible to a user other than *root* *(by e.g adding the 'mysticbbs', or a dedicated system user, to 'shadow' group(?)..I'm not even going to test that. Though i guess that could also be a potential workaround.)*.</strike>

**EDIT: Adding the user that dropbear is being run under to `shadow` group just seems easier..And after all [`/etc/shadow`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/) is still [*chmod 640*](http://www.filepermissions.com/file-permission/640) (writable to *root* user only, though readable to *shadow* group)**

```
ls -la /etc/shadow
```

> -rw-r-----    1 root     shadow         503 Feb  6 16:33 /etc/shadow

*(Note: Probably not recommended in where high security is top priority though)*